# changing href value of UIWebView using js

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I have the following code:

```
NSString *stripLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).parentNode.href=%@", pt.x, pt.y, @"http://www.test.com"];
NSLog(@"JS IS %@", stripLink);
[self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:stripLink];

NSString *testHref = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).parentNode.href", pt.x, pt.y];
NSLog(@"FINAL HREF IS %@", [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:testHref]);
```

However the final URL is always the old one, why is this? ? What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've forgotten to enclose your new URL in quotes. Try this, and tell us:

```
NSString *stripLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).parentNode.href='%@'", pt.x, pt.y, @"http://www.test.com"];
```

(see the 'quotes' around the `'%@'` ?)

Comment: By the way, you should allow some time to elapse before you check for your new URL, it might not have been loaded right after you've changed it.